# Query hibernate lógica

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public boolean minimoUmSuperUsuario(Usuario usuario, Session sessionExterna) throws HibernateException {
    Criteria crit = sessionExterna.createCriteria(Usuario.class);

    return (Long) crit.uniqueResult() > 0;
}
```

Preciso fazer a seguinte tarefa:

```
select * from usuario where superusuario and usuarioativo = true
```

Fazer este select no hibernate em um metodo boolean e retornar:

```
if quantide de super usuario e ativo == 1 retornar true 
else false.
```

Não sei como implementar isto no método acima.

Comment: Acrdito que na sua `query` você precise colocar assim: `select * from usuario where superusuario = true and usuarioativo = true`

Answer (score 0):

Se quer usar Criteria do Hibernate:

```
public boolean minimoUmSuperUsuario(Usuario usuario, Session sessionExterna) throws HibernateException {
  Criteria crit = sessionExterna.createCriteria(Usuario.class);
  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("ativo",true));

  return (Long) crit.uniqueResult() > 0;
}
```

Para mais detalhes consulte [Hibernate_User_Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria).